# what is the difference between @Query and @path in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I wanted to use retrofit library for parsing and posting the data by passing some parameters. But When defining model class some times we will use @Serialized in-front of variable, What is the use of that Serialized.And What is the difference between @Get and @Query in passing params to API.Can Any one explain the difference.

Comment: No one better to explain then [Officail Docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 9):

Lets say you have api method `@GET("/api/item/{id}/subitem/")` so by using `@Path("id")` you can specify id for item in path. However your api may take additional parameters in query like sort, lastupdatetime, limit etc so you add those at end of url by `@Query(value = "sort") String sortQuery`

So full method will look like:

```
@GET("/api/item/{id}/subitem")
SubItem getSubItem(@Path("id") int itemId, @Query("sort") String sortQuery, @Query("limit") int itemsLimit);
```

and calling `api.getSubItem(5, "name", 10)` will produce url `@GET("/api/item/5/subitem/?sort=name&limit=10")`

and `@Get` is HTTP method

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp says

> Two commonly used methods for a request-response between a client and
>   server are: GET and POST.
>
> GET - Requests data from a specified resource POST - Submits data to
>   be processed to a specified resource

Answer (score 0):

`@GET` is request method. You mark method with that.

`@Query` is query parameter (i.e. the one in the URL). You mark method parameters with that.

`@Serialized` probably does not belong to Retrofit, look at its package name (move cursor there and press `Ctrl+Q in Android studio)